# MySql textbook syntax wrong?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have 3 tables: Employee(EmpCode,EmpName,Birth,DeptCode)
Dept(DeptCode, DeptName, Location, Telephone)
Project(PrCode,PrName, Budget)
Participate(EmpCode,PrCode, Hours).

I want to find the employees who participate in all projects. My textbook uses this query to find the EmpCode of employees working in both Project 1 and Project2: `select EmpCode from Participate group by EmpCode having set(PrCode) contains('Pr1','Pr2')`

Using this, I made a query to find the employees participating in all projects:

```
select EmpName,Birth, DeptCode
from Employee
where EmpCode in (
    select EmpCode as Employee_Code,DeptCode
    from Participate
    group by DeptCode
    having set(Employee_Code) contains EmpCode );
```

But it gives me a syntax error! Please help me thank you very much.
P/S: This is the full code:

```
create table Employee(
EmpCode int unsigned not null auto_increment,
EmpName varchar(40) not null default '',
Birth varchar(40) not null default '',
DeptCode int unsigned not null default 0,
primary key (EmpCode)
);

create table Dept(
DeptCode int unsigned not null auto_increment,
DeptName varchar(40) not null default '',
Location varchar(40) not null default '',
Tel varchar(40) not null default '',
primary key (DeptCode)
);

create table Project(
PrCode int unsigned not null auto_increment,
PrName varchar(40) not null default '',
Budget varchar(40) not null default '',
primary key (PrCode)
);

create table Participate(
EmpCode int unsigned not null ,
DeptCode int unsigned not null ,
Hours int unsigned not null default 0,
primary key (EmpCode, DeptCode)
);


insert into Employee values 
(501,'Nguyen Van A', '26/03/1974',301),
(502,'Pham Thi B', '10/01/1990',302),
(503,'abcdsfdsf', '06/06/1991',302),
(570,'Tran Minh T', '25/02/1985',303);

insert into Dept values
(301,'HR','Bi mat','029393943'),
(302,'R&D','Quan net','01938228329'),
(303,'PR','Everywhere','024032940');

insert into Project values
(201,'on linear programming','1 trieu'),
(203,'military secret','1 ty ty'),
(204,'Skynet','1 ty USD'),
(210,'Terminator','100 trieu');

insert into Participate values
(501, 201, 1000),
(501, 203, 2000),
(502, 204, 10),
(503, 210, 220),
(501, 204, 7474),
(501, 210, 103),
(570, 204, 11);

alter table Participate
    add foreign key (EmpCode) references Employee(EmpCode),
    add foreign key (PrCode) references Project(PrCode);

alter table Employee
    add foreign key (DeptCode) references Dept(DeptCode);

select EmpName,Birth, DeptCode
    from Employee
    where EmpCode in (
        select EmpCode as Employee_Code,DeptCode
        from Participate
        group by DeptCode
        having set(Employee_Code) contains EmpCode );
```

Comment: Can you please post your schema and the error that you are getting?

Comment: I've given an answer that (may) help you get rid of the syntax error, but seeing the actual error code might help. Also, I think there's a lot more going on here, I don't really understand what you're doing in the subquery, it looks like bad practice to have `group by` without an aggregate function. I suspect you have more problems than syntax errors, so I'd post the schema as well if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @keda I have posted the full code

Comment: Well one problem I get is that you don't have PrCode inside the participate table yet you try to set it as a foreign key; You need to add that column to participate.

Comment: @McAdam331 I don't understand. Each Employee works only in a Department, therefore a DeptCode in Employee should reference to a DeptCode in Dept. And the Participate table describe many-to-many relationships.  Putting it into Participate just doesn't make sense

Comment: Well you can't have a foreign key to a column that doesn't exist. So either remove the foreign key in your alter table statement for `PrCode` if you don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a syntax error is because of your `IN` clause. You are querying for two columns:

```
SELECT EmpCode AS Employee_Code, DeptCode
```

However, you are only checking it against one column:

```
WHERE EmpCode IN (..)
```

To fix it, you need to do one of two things, depending on your problem:

- Change your WHERE clause to check for both `WHERE EmpCode, DeptCode IN (...)`
- Change your subquery to only select `EmpCode`, but based on your aggregation I think the first option is what you want to do to achieve the correct results.

EDIT:

Another possible syntax error could be using the table alias in your having clause. You may need to change it to `HAVING SET(EmpCode)` instead of using the `Employee_Code` alias.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is not 100% clear to me, I based my answer just on your goal declared **to find the EmpCode of employees working in both Project 1 and Project2**.

Here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47340/2

```
SELECT Employee.EmpName, Employee.Birth, Employee.DeptCode, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Participate.PrCode)
FROM Employee
INNER  JOIN Participate
ON Participate.EmpCode = Employee.EmpCode
  AND Participate.DeptCode = Employee.DeptCode
  AND Participate.PrCode IN (201,203)
GROUP BY Employee.EmpCode
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Participate.PrCode) = 2;
```

Check my sqlfiddle because your database initialization failed. The sql statements set you've posted can not be executed as you post. So I did some changes just to get this database working.

To achieve that I did some guesses/changes like:

```
create table Participate(
EmpCode int unsigned not null ,
DeptCode int unsigned not null ,
Hours int unsigned not null default 0,
primary key (EmpCode, DeptCode)
);

insert into Dept values
(301,'HR','Bi mat','029393943'),
(302,'R&D','Quan net','01938228329'),
(303,'PR','Everywhere','024032940');

insert into Project values
(201,'on linear programming','1 trieu'),
(203,'military secret','1 ty ty'),
(204,'Skynet','1 ty USD'),
(210,'Terminator','100 trieu');
insert into Participate values
(501, 201, 1000),
(501, 203, 2000),
(502, 204, 10),
(503, 210, 220),
(501, 204, 7474),
(501, 210, 103),
(570, 204, 11);
```

Take a look on

```
insert into Participate values
(501, 201, 1000),
```

code `201` should be `DeptCode` according to the `create table Participate` but if you see other inserts it seems that `201` is `Project.PrCode`! So I set `PrCode` column for `Participate` and put it on 2nd place to make sense for the inserts data you posted.

Another thing I did change:

```
create table Participate(
...
primary key (EmpCode, DeptCode)
...
```

It says that combination of any `EmpCode, DeptCode` should be unique in this table. But it has no sense either. Usually every employee (`EmpCode`) belongs to ONE department (`DeptCode`) that means if we want to use Employee in different projects he will mostly keep the same Department ID (`DeptCode`) for every project. That's why I removed that key from the table definition.

I have some more comments, but I guess that is enough for now.

And you are very welcome if any questions! :-)